# Today my global User Icon changed. Why?

Tags: bug, gravatar, identicon

My user icon, which I have used since my start with this site, changed. I know I do not use a personalized one, but I have gotten a sentimental attachment to it. Has the rendering been changed for a good reason?  I have attached the screenshot from my flair page which shows the original (purple) rendering, as opposed to the newer (khaki) one.

[image]

EDIT: I have digested the suggested question this is determined to be a duplicate of, and have this to add:

1. The account used on this site has, is, and continues to be, the same for my entire tenure.
2. Using the 'Change your image' button on my profile page yields a suggested THIRD icon for the same account. I didn't choose it, because it's clearly the ugliest so far.
3. If it must be changed through no input or choice of my own, I would (but shall not like it) stay with the khaki one.

Comment: More to the point: How can I change it *back*?  That question doesn't seem to have been answered anywhere.

Comment: @Wildcard if you can get the one you like save it to your harddrive and upload it via your profile settings. that way if Gravatar messes up again after this gets fixed (Smith's Law - *"Murphy was an optimist"*) it wont matter

Comment: @Memor-X, well actually I already saved it long ago, as soon as I noticed my sentimental attachment.  :)  So *I'm* set.